# How to install/upgrade Chromium offline?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, chromium, offline

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, in which I also use Chromium browser.
Now, I always install/upgrade files on Ubuntu in offline mode. Though, I never had any problem with any application ever, I never could do so with Chromium.

Every time, I try to do, it says that installation will break. I have all dependencies downloaded and none of them are being installed. I have even uninstalled previous version of Chromium, but no use. The result stays same. But, if I'll try to do so online, then Ubuntu downloads same files and then install/upgrade Chromium.

Can't one do so in *offline* mode?

UPDATE [14.02.2014]: Ok,I think there is some problem with updating browsers offline. I was not able to do so with Firefox 27.0 release, with similar errors, though, all other updates are running perfectly, even update from 12.04. to 12.04.4.

Comment: Can you give us the actual errors you're getting in console and what method of installation you are using offline (source, binary or package)

Comment: I am trying to install via deb package.
I generated package download script via synaptic, got the file addresses, downloaded them on other PC and try to install them.
This is what I do always and things  go smooth, except for Chromium.
I am trying to install via terminal (dpkg) and output I am getting is:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MMYYFw01

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best solution for *offline* mode is building **Chromium** by himself, "deliberately" for your **Ubuntu** only. Common guide for Linux is here:

[Chromium: Linux Build Instructions](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions)

Though, this way contains some **Warning!** for you cause it require numerous *Prerequisites* to be installed to make clean **Chromium** build.

Comment: That's too technical for me and I suppose for many out theirs.......

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the pasted output, the best option would be to attempt to run the Synaptic-generated download script again as something was corrupted en route.  Failing that you might try utilizing [apt-offline](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apt-offline) which does do some checksum checking while downloading.

Comment: Installed apt-offline, but don't know how to use it. One tut on askubuntu tells it, but through linux pc only. Whereas, as per apt-offline, one can use it to download via windows pc as well....

Comment: @A.K.Pandey Instructions on usage are available here: http://docs.xubuntu.org/1310/offline-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Cube](https://launchpad.net/camicricube)** for downloading packages in a computer with internet connection and installing it offline. Same functionalities as Synaptic but it validates every .deb packages it will get using md5sums to prevent corrupted .deb files.

Comment: Issue is not deb files being wrong...... they are the ones, from repository. Downloaded them again and same result, so I am sure that's not issue.